# Replace 5 dots with a single space

Tags: bash, command, tr

I have a title that has 5 consecutive dots which I'd like replaced with just one space using bash script. Doing this is not helping:

```
tr '.....' ' '
```

Obviously because it's replacing the five dots with 5 spaces.

Basically, I have a title that I want changed to a slug. So I'm using:

```
tr A-Z a-z | tr '[:punct:] [:blank:]' '-'
```

to change everything to lowercase and change any punctuation mark and spaces to a hyphen, but I'm stuck with the dots.

The title I'm using is something like: `Believe.....Right Now`

So I want that turned into `believe-right-now`

How do I change the 5 dots to a single space?

Comment: This question doesn't deserve a downvote.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need sed or awk. Your original tr command should do the trick, you just need to add the -s flag. After tr translates the desired characters into hyphens, -s will squeeze all repeated hyphens into one:

```
tr A-Z a-z | tr -s '[:punct:] [:blank:]' '-'
```

I'm not sure what the input/output context is for you, but I tested the above as follows, and it worked for me:

```
tr A-Z a-z <<< "Believe.....Right Now" | tr -s '[:punct:] [:blank:]' '-'
```

output:

> believe-right-now

See http://www.ss64.com/bash/tr.html for reference.

Answer (score 4):

Transliterations are performed with mappings, which means each character is mapped into something else -- or delete, with `tr -d`. This is the reason why `tr '.....' ' '` does not work.

Replacing *five dots* with space:

- using `sed` with extended regular expressions:

  ```
  $ sed -r 's/\.{5}/ /g' <<< "Believe.....Right Now"
  Believe Right Now
  ```
- using `sed` without `-r`:

  ```
  $ sed 's/\.\{5\}/ /g' <<< "Believe.....Right Now"
  Believe Right Now
  ```
- using parameter expansion:

  ```
  $ text="foo.....bar.....zzz" && echo "${text//...../ }"
  foo bar zzz
  ```

Replacing *five dots* and spaces with `-`:

```
$ sed -r 's/\.{5}| /-/g' <<< "Believe.....Right Now"
Believe-Right-Now
```

Full replacement -- ditching `tr` usage:

```
$ sed -re 's/\.{5}| /-/g' -e 's/([A-Z])/\l&/g' <<< "Believe.....Right Now"
believe-right-now
```

or, in case your `sed` version does not support the flag `-r`, you may use:

```
$ sed -e 's/\.\{5\}\| /-/g' -e 's/\([A-Z]\)/\l&/g' <<< "Believe.....Right Now"
believe-right-now
```

Comment: You can make the `sed` expression a little more readable by using the option `-r`: `sed -r 's/\.{5}/ /g'`

Comment: This is what I'm getting: sed/ illegal option -- r
usage/ sed script [-Ealn] [-i extension] [file ...]
       sed [-Ealn] [-i extension] [-e script] ... [-f script_file] ... [file ...]

Comment: @phptinkerer Your `sed` version may not allow extended regular expressions. Please, check my edit.

Comment: All I want is to change 5 dots to a single space. I'm using this shell script in Keyboard Maestro so I'm not sure all this works. Please see [this](http://notes.onethingwell.org/images/km-tumblr-safari.png) for reference. Scroll down to where it says Execute Shell Script

Comment: @phptinkerer In case all you want is the *five dots* replacement, the first solution is surely going to work. If your concern is on how to plug the `sed` in the command line you pointed, just use pipes: `... | sed 's/\.\{5\}/ /g'`

Comment: @Rubens thanks, that's when I got the error mentioned in my first comment (using the pipes)

Comment: @phptinkerer Without the `-r` option you shouldn't have any problem to execute `... | sed 's/\.\{5\}/ /g'` -- at least the error should not be `sed/ illegal option -- r usage/ sed script [-Ealn] [-i extension] [file ...] ...`.

Comment: `-r` is a GNU sed option. Other seds WILL give you that error message.

Answer (score 2):

```
$ cat file
Believe.....Right Now

$ awk '{gsub(/[[:punct:][:space:].]+/,"-"); print tolower($0)}' file
believe-right-now
```

Comment: Somehow this looks right, but since I'm using shell script in Keyboard Maestro, this won't work for me. I want it in the format I mentioned in my question without the $ and variables. I hope that made sense.

Comment: Please see [this](http://notes.onethingwell.org/images/km-tumblr-safari.png) for reference. Scroll down to where it says Execute Shell Script

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand why you're confused. The `$` was my prompt (the standard UNIX shell prompt), otherwise just use the script as-is.

Comment: my apologies, I'm only confused because I'm not aware of the syntax. I'm not knowledgable in scripting, that's why I thought it wont work. So based on the reference link I mentioned earlier how do I have to enter the string?

Comment: EXACTLY as I wrote it, best I can tell. Why not try it and see?